# Issue with the performance of multiprocessing method against numpy.loadtxt()

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I usually use `numpy.loadtxt(filename)` when I want to load files from the disk. Recently, I got a node of 36 processors so I thought to utilize the multiprocessing approach to load files such that each processor loads a portion of the file and eventually the root processor gathers them. I am expecting the files to be loaded are always huge (at least 5 GB) so using such a multiprocessing approach is reasonable.

To do so, I wrote the following method that simply loads any given file from the disk using multiple processors. I came from `C` world so I found out that using [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library satisfies what I need. Note that `jobs` is an integer indicating the number of jobs in the file. Each job is a binary value written at a line in the file.

```
def load_dataset(COM, jobs, rank, size, filepath):
    start = time.time()
    C = None
    r = None
    rank_indices = ()
    job_batch = jobs / size
    for i in range((rank * job_batch), ((rank + 1) * job_batch)):
        rank_indices = rank_indices + (i,)

    C1 = []
    with open(filepath) as fd:
        for n, line in enumerate(fd):
            if n in rank_indices:
                s = line.splitlines()
                W = [int(n) for n in s[0].split()]
                W = np.asarray(W, np.int8)
                C1.append(W)
        C1 = np.asarray(C1)

    gather_C = COM.gather(C1, root=0)
    COM.Barrier()

    if rank == 0:
        print('\t\t>> Rank 0 is now gathering from other processors!! Wait please!')
        C = np.asarray(list(itertools.chain(*gather_C)), dtype=np.int8)
        end = time.time()
        print('Loading time= %s' % (end - start))
    del C1, gather_C
    return C
```

However, it turns out that `numpy.loadtxt(filename)` is really faster than my method which is surprising!! I think I have a bug in my code so I am sharing it hoping that someone can spot any bug that causes the performance issue. All ideas and hints are also appreciated.

Comment: I think your bottleneck is disk IO (not CPU). When you use multiprocessing you will still read from the same disk. Additionally  you will have overhead for multiprocessing and joining pieces into a single array, which explains why it's slower compared to normal `numpy.loadtxt(filename)`...

Comment: Each of your processes reads the whole file, even though it only processes a subset of the lines.  `loadtxt` is much like your inner loop, except I don't think it converts each line into an array.  It's left as a list.  So the final `np.array` works from a list of lists.

Comment: `pandas` csv reader is faster, using compiled code (at least in some cases).